# Exec command doesn't work as expected

Tags: php

I'm trying to launch a CLI command from a PHP script:

in particular I wanna use this command `convert a.png a.tif` to convert an image to tiff.

When I launch this command from CLI it works as expected but if I launch from a PHP script with the following code it doesn't create any tiff image in my folder:

```
$exec = "convert a.png a.tif";
exec($exec,$yaks,$err);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yaks);
echo "$err";
echo "</pre>";
```

Moreover `$yaks` is empty and `$err` is set to 127.

I'm not an expert, why this doesn't work as expected?

Best regards

**UPDATE**

I used this command instead `$exec = "convert 4.png 4.tif 2>&1";` and I got in return `[0] => sh: convert: command not found`

This seems to me strange since I can use it from CLI!

**FINAL UPDATE**

Thanks a lot guys!

```
$exec = "/usr/local/bin/convert a.png a.tif";
```

This command solved the problem!
You're great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should enter fullpath to "convert" and may be files.

err 127 - file not found

Comment: I'm trying to write the full path, but I think this isn't the main error, take a look at the update.

Comment: as I said, you should use full path for convert. I think it near /usr/bin/convert. How you run php-script from CLI?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the 'convert' binary isn't in any of the directories on the `PATH` PHP is using.  You could try using the full path, e.g. `/opt/local/bin/convert` or whatever the path is.

You could also modify the PATH used by PHP (but I don't know how).

Comment: For future reference, I think (but I haven't tested) this is how you modify the PATH used by PHP:
`putenv("PATH=xyz");`

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script probably doesn't know where to find these things you're referring to in the `exec` command. When you run this from the command line, the shell will look for them in the directory you are in at that point in time; but when you run it from PHP, it probably defaults to the PHP dir and not the specific dir in which your files are. So write out the full path.

Comment: It doens't recognize convert as valid command however I'm trying to use full path