# shell_exec not working with nmap command

Tags: php, shell-exec

I got a problem with the `shell_exec` php function, here is a example code:

```
$output = shell_exec('nmap -PS80 -n -oG - --send-ip 11.11.11.11');

if ( $output )
{
     echo "Output found...";
}
else
{
     var_dump( $output );
}
```

It does return: *`NULL`*, but when I change the `shell_exec` command to the following:

`$output = shell_exec('echo 1');`

then the output is: `Output found...` so its working properly, and there is no problems with permissions or safe mode (which is off , by the way).

It is having a problems with execute the `nmap` command. I've check that command in the shell command line in putty and its working properly:

```
# nmap -PS80 -n -oG - --send-ip 11.11.11.11
# Nmap 5.61TEST2 scan initiated Tue Feb 28 13:55:41 2012 as: nmap -PS80 -n -oG - --send-ip 11.11.11.11
# Nmap done at Tue Feb 28 13:55:43 2012 -- 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify full path to nmap like `/usr/local/bin/nmap`. PHP might not know about nmap location. Enjoy!

Comment: PHP is just executing the `shell_exec` function, so there is nothing related to the nmap location, same as `echo` - do I have to specify full path to the `echo` ? I dont think so =/

Comment: because you don't understand how nmap registered in your shell. Look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401824/exec-command-doesnt-work-as-expected/9401924#9401924

Comment: Wtf, it worked while I replaced `nmap [..]` with the `/usr/local/bin/nmap` (where the nmap executable is located). Thank you! Could you edit your answer a bit, so I can rate up you answer, since I've down rated it, and now I feel so stupid - sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to resort to [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead, which gives you greater error diagnostics:

```
// Capture outout from STDERR as well
$command = "nmap ... 2>&1";

exec($command, $output, $return_var);

// If return code is not zero, the command failed
if ($return_var != 0) 
{
    // dump all output, including error messages
    var_dump($output);
}
```

Comment: It does return: `array(0) { } array(0) { }`.