# How to use Nmap in PHP exec

Tags: php, nmap

I would like to call Nmap from PHP.

IF I do that :

```
exec('nmap', $output);
var_dump( $output );
```

It works, I get the classic "Usage of Nmap" text.

But as soon as I tried to run an UDP check like

```
exec('nmap -p 586 -sU xx.xx.xx.xx', $output);
var_dump( $output );
```

It don't work anymore, with no output.

What am I missing?

Regards

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483227/shell-exec-not-working-with-nmap-command

Comment: No it is not a duplicate! Using the full path doesn't change anything. It works with few options like -v but with -sU it fails

Comment: Not only was the full path mentioned in there, but different code was also used.

Comment: You are still wrong. The problem was not a question of path or different code. The problem was that NMAP is not fully functional with the webservers user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important notice:** NMAP is **not fully functional with the webservers user** (apache, www-data, ...).
**Only** `root` can do everything with NMAP.

I'd use [`popen()`](http://php.net/popen).

```
$stream = popen('/usr/bin/nmap -p 586 -sU xx.xx.xx.xx', 'r');

while (!feof($stream)) {
    //Make sure you use semicolon at the end of command
    $buffer = fread($stream, 1024);
    echo $buffer, PHP_EOL;
}

pclose($stream);
```

Or worth trying:

```
// Start output buffering
ob_start();
// Flush COMPLETE output of nmap
fpassthru('/usr/bin/nmap -p 586 -sU xx.xx.xx.xx');
// Capture output buffer contents
$output = ob_get_contents();
// Shutdown output buffers
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Your notice explain everything I guess. For example the -v option works, but not the -sU .

Comment: You can use nmap without root but **many** options don't work then. If you have SSH access, try with root `su www-data` (or apache,..) then run nmap from console. It will fail :-/

Comment: @Khorne Hint: You can setup php-fpm (fcgi) (better with nginx I guess) and let the PHP script be executed by root from the web.

Answer (score 2):

Certain Nmap features require root privileges to run. `-sU` UDP port scanning is one of these. On Linux, the full list is:

- `-sU` UDP port scans
- `-sS` TCP SYN scans
- `-sA/W/M/N/F/X` TCP scans with various flags
- `-PE/PP/PM` ICMP host discovery probes
- `-sO` IP Protocol scans
- `-sY/Z` SCTP scans
- `-O` OS detection
- `--traceroute` tracerouting
- Pretty much all the IDS evasion options

Needless to say, it's probably *NOT A GOOD IDEA* to let your web server run Nmap commands as root. I also caution you to be very strict about what user input you let into the Nmap command line. Lots of Nmap features can be abused to execute arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the backtick operator (`) to run Nmap. That will return the output into a variable. So:

```
$output = `nmap -p 586 -sU xx.xx.xx.xx`;
```

More on the backtick operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Same as before. "Nmap" alone works and return the Usage text, but nothing as soon as I add option after Nmap