# Instagraph PHP photo editing exec() function does not execute function, but works on command line?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, exec, instagram

I am trying to add the gotham feature found in Instagram via PHP and ImageMagick (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-instagram-filters-with-php/) The script given doesn't work, but the commands do. When I generate the commands and copy and paste them to a command line, they work fine. Yet when I try to execute them with exec(), they do not work. I looked at the output given and it says the command is not found. I have safety mode off in php.ini and exec() is not a disabled function. I have tried adding ampersands and '2>&1' but to no avail. Why is it that exec() does not understand the command? Here is the script

```
function gotham($image) {
    exec("convert " . $image . " -modulate 120,10,100 -fill '#222b6d' -colorize 20 -gamma 0.5 -contrast -contrast " . $image . " 2>&1", $output1);
    exec("convert " . $image . " -bordercolor black -border 20x20 " . $image . " 2>&1", $output2);
}
```

Here is what comes from the var_dump of the $output variables:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "sh: convert: command not found" } array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "sh: convert: command not found" }
```

Comment: Check chmod and chgrp. Make sure that php have permission to run Imagick

Comment: I just chmod 777 and then chgrp the same, still it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have path problem. Try these

```
  exec("/path/to/Imagick/bin/convert -version", $output2);
```

Or

```
  exec("usr/local/bin/convert -version", $output);
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401824/exec-command-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

First determine where imagemagick installed on your system. You can do this from the terminal by running

```
whereis convert
```

To troubleshoot the permission issues, login as the user running the web server. This is usually `apache`/`nobody`/`www-data` depending on your distro and/or setup. In terminal run the following:

```
su - www-data
```

The above switches the current user to the one running the web server. In my case this `www-data`.

Now run the `convert` command with the full path (as determined by `whereis convert` from earlier and arguments in your php script. If there are no permission issues, this should execute fine. In most cases, you should see the same error as when running this from the php script in the web server.

Check permissions of the convert program by running

```
ls -l `whereis convert`
```

Comment: Alright that worked, but now I get dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib [1] => Referenced from: /Users/ulmer/Dropbox/insta2/../../../../opt/local/bin/convert [2] => Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0

Comment: Mac 10.7.3 running PHP on a MAMP server

Comment: This might help. http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8245 Why aren't you using the imagemagick php extension? See https://mrhelly.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/getting-imagemagick-running-on-mamp/